# Why can’t we use an arbitrary poset/Boolean algebra when doing set-theoretic forcing

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, forcing

I’m trying to read up on the Boolean-algebra approach to forcing, and I’m noticing a confusion that makes me thing I’ve misunderstood something fundamental about the process. Concretely, it seems to me like the method should work for almost any poset/Boolean algebra rather than us having to carefully pick an appropriate one (e.g the arrays of partial functions ordered by reverse inclusion for C.H). Clearly this isn’t true but I’m not sure where I’m going wrong:

Using the Boolean Algebra approach, we have that an element $p$ forces $\phi$ iff $p<[[\phi]]^B$, where $[[\phi]]^B$ is the “Boolean truth value” assigned to $\phi$ in $M^B$, because if we mod out by any Generic Ultrafilter $U$ containing $p$ then any sentences with “truth value” $p$ become true in $M[U]$, and therefore due to the definition of Ultrafilters so too do any sentences with truth value $[[\phi]]^B$.

My confusion is that this seems like a very weak condition, and that it seems like since $\phi$ will be assigned some value for any choice of $B$, we can find a lesser element in the $B$ that therefore forces $\phi$ without having to take care to choose specifically what poset/Boolean Algebra we need. In other words and for concreteness - what specifically fails if we try to force the negation of C.H with some arbitrary atomless Boolean algebras rather than the set of partial functions actually used?

Comment: The Boolean approach does work fine with any complete Boolean algebra, and any poset can be densely embedded into a complete Boolean algebra. Or are you asking why not *every* $B$ works to force $\lnot\text{CH}$? That's certainly not the case since the poset that adds one Cohen real (instead of $\aleph_2$ many) does not violate $\text{CH}$. Different choices of poset result in different properties of the generic extension, that's what forcing is all about

Comment: $p$ forces $\phi$ if $p\leq[[\phi]]^B$, not $p<[[\phi]]^B$. Which book are you reading? I recommend first two chapters of Bell, and then you can look at Jech. Reading Bell you will know that we don't need to have a classical two-valued model-- a Boolean valued model where CH has truth value zero is enough to show the consistency of $\lnot\text{CH}$. Jech does similar thing and then translate it to the countable transitive model approach.

Comment: I see two parts in your question. First, can we see arbitrary Boolean algebras? No, we need complete Boolean algebras in order to define the truth values of quantified formulas. Second, why won't an arbitrary (complete) Boolean algebra force whatever $\phi$ we want, since $\phi$ will get some Boolean value and we can find a smaller $p$? In general, the Boolean value of $\phi$ might be $0$. Since forcing conditions have to be nonzero elements of the Boolean algebra, this situation would not enable us to force $\phi$. The Boolean algebra must be chosen carefully to give $\phi$ a nonzero  value.

Comment: I think it will help to look at a concrete example of two forcings that create radically different situations - e.g. adding $\aleph_2$-many Cohen reals vs. adding a bijection from $\omega_1$ to $2^{\aleph_0}$ via countable initial segments (which force $\neg\mathsf{CH}$ and $\mathsf{CH}$ respectively).

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you! I was getting at the second question but maybe didn’t word it well. I was considering something like that, but I’m still somewhat confused because if it’s assigned 0 in the “wrong” Boolean-values model doesn’t that mean $[[\neg\phi]]^B = 1$ and therefore the sentence we’re trying to force is inconsistent with ZF? I thought any consistent sentence must get *some* non-zero value in any $[[•]]^B$

Comment: @Ablation_nation If $\phi$ gets value $0$ in the Boolean valued model built using $B$, then $\neg\phi$ gets value $1$ in that particular model, but it may get other values in models built using other Boolean algebras. Such a $\phi$ may well be consistent with ZFC.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Ah ok thanks I think I misunderstood the conditional here as being bi-directional - being a theorem implies a Boolean value of 1 but not the converse I guess. This has helped clear things up for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has mostly been answered in the comments. Elaborating on those:

Suppose $M$ is a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and $\mathbb{B}$ is a complete Boolean algebra in $M$. Then in the Boolean-valued model $M^\mathbb{B}$, each $\mathsf{ZFC}$-theorem gets truth value $1$ but the converse fails. This is clarified in the comment thread.

That said, note that the converse does hold if we *quantify over* both models and Boolean algebras in the first place. Precisely, the following *are* equivalent:

- $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash\varphi$.
- For each $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ and each $\mathbb{B}\in M$ such that $M\models$ "$\mathbb{B}$ is a complete Boolean algebra," we have $[\varphi]_{M^\mathbb{B}}=1$.

This is actually trivial: if we let ${\bf 2}$ to be the two-element Boolean algebra we get $M^{\bf 2}\cong M$ (note that no matter what $M$ is, ${\bf 2}$ "lives in" $M$ in an unproblematic way), and so "True in all Boolean-valued models" implies "True in all models in the usual sense." Now just use Godel's completeness theorem to get from $\models$ to $\vdash$.

Note that quantifying over models as well as Boolean algebras is crucial here: if $M\models\mathsf{ZFC+\neg V=L}$ then $M^{\mathbb{B}}\models\mathsf{\neg V=L}$ for every complete BA $\mathbb{B}\in M$, but of course (hopefully!) $\mathsf{ZFC}\not\vdash \mathsf{\neg V=L}$. If you're interested in looking at what happens when we fix a model but consider varying the BAs, the term **generic multiverse** will be of interest. (The topic of **$\Omega$-logic** is also relevant, although quite technical.)